# How to create a variable that is the lowest possible number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

What I have here is an algorithm that finds the highest value in each subarray and pushes it onto a separate array (final).

I want to let the variable 'value' equal to the lowest possible number so that any negative number can be considered higher than 'value'

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var final=[];
  arr.map(sub => {
    let value = 0; //issue
    sub.map(num => {
      if(num>value){value=num};
    })
    final.push(value)
  })
  return final;
}
console.log(largestOfFour([[17, 23, 25, 12], [25, 7, 34, 48], [4, -10, 18, 21], [-72, -3, -17, -10]]));
```

In this example the last subarray returns 0 since non of the numbers in that subarray were higher than the initial value of 'value' which is 0.

I want it to return '-3' instead since it's the highest number in the subarray.

Comment: `let value = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;`

Comment: You're asking the wrong question, what you're looking for is how to find the maximum of four numbers. Just assume the first element of the array is the highest, then test the others against it.

Comment: In the future, beware the dreaded [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that @ChrisG alluded to in his comment. While it's essential to provide the steps you've taken, it's often better off to ask about the end-goal itself, rather than the proposed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set `value` to `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` but for what it's worth, I'd recommend simply using `reduce` instead of `map` in your inner function. That way, the inner loop will start with `sub[0]` as an initial value rather than depending on any placeholder.

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var final = arr.map(sub => sub.reduce((num, value) => Math.max(num, value)));
  return final;
}
console.log(largestOfFour([
  [17, 23, 25, 12],
  [25, 7, 34, 48],
  [4, -10, 18, 21],
  [-72, -3, -17, -10]
]));
```

Comment: used sub[0] just because It's shorter than Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3):

*It would appear you're simply looking for the max of each array.*

Using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Math#max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) you could do something like this.

```js
const data = [[17, 23, 25, 12], [25, 7, 34, 48], [4, -10, 18, 21], [-72, -3, -17, -10]];

const res = data.map(arr=>Math.max(...arr));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Good catch. Even simpler than mine.